# Import file error

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform

I'm modifying an open source project installed with CocoaPods and when I try adding

```
 #import <Parse/Parse.h>
```

in the header of one of the open source files I get

```
<Parse/Parse.h> file not found error**.
```

So apparently I have a framework folder under both my project directory and under my Pods folder.

So if having the **Parse** framework under my project directory isn't enough, do I also have to add the **Parse** Framework under my Pods framework folder too?

Just for fun I also tried

```
 #import "Parse/Parse.h"
```

but that doesn't work either.

------------**UPDATE**--------

As suggested I deleted Parse from my framework in my project and imported it again. Made sure "Relative to Group" is checked and not folder.

**Picture Description**

1) Added to Link Binary With Libraries

2) File Inspector shows framework is relative to Group

3) Shows that a file in my project Directory using the framework has no problem using it

4) However in my Pods folder where the open source project lies, the open source file where I've added the framework still shows an error with quotations ("") and angle brackets (<>)

5) With "Parse/Parse.h"

[image: Added to Link Binary With Libraries]

[image: File Inspector shows framework is relative to Group]

[image: Shows that a file in my project Directory using the framework has no problem using it]

[image: However in my Pods folder where the open source project lies, the open source file where I've added the framework still shows an error with quotations ("") and angle brackets (<>)]

[image: With "Parse/Parse.h"]

Comment: So are you definitely using Cocoapods? Do any other installed pods not show up?

Comment: Can you try dragging the Parse SDK into your project? If you do, be sure to import it as a `group reference`, not a `folder reference` -- the latter can lead to a file not found error

Comment: Yep, I'm using Cocoapods to install the Open Source project I'm using and I double checked that group is checked when importing the framework. So to use a framework in the open source project, it should have worked if I already have the framework in my project directory?

Comment: By default, Pods doesn't have the Parse framework in its frameworks directory but the directory does have Accounts.framework which is used in the open source project. I have the Parse framework in my own project directory but from what was suggested, I should be able to access the framework in the open source file just by having the Parse framework in my project directory

Comment: "Do any other installed pods not show up?" - Good question, So it seems frameworks like AVFoundation, Bolts, Security, etc work, but when I add other third party frameworks not in the system like FBSDKCoreKit or Parse  it doesn't work in my open source file but it does for files in my project Directory

Comment: Wait...Bolts isn't a framework included in xcode by default but I can import it without an error showing up... confused now, but imma think more about this, thanks it's progress haha and now i'm just spamming the comment section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
#import "Parse/Parse.h"
```

but you have to have the framework added to your project:

Project Navigator =>  =>  => Build Phases => Link Binary with Libraries => "+" => Add Other => (Navigate & Choose your framework).

Make sure if/when given a choice to reference it relative to project and as a group (not a folder). If not then select the framework in the Project Navigator and then in the File Inspector View make sure that it's Location is NOT absolute.

Also, if the framework is going to be embedded in the final application make sure that the target has a Copy Files build phase for the framework.

Comment: Thanks, turns out I just found the CocoaPods version of Parse and now I can use it in the open source file as well as files within my Project Directory. (Had to delete the framework linked in my project directory)